# UISearchBar Placeholder besides another Text

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uisearchbar, placeholder

How to put a placeholder text besides the text entered by user in the UISearchBar Text.

Or even to put some text in gray if the above cannot work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make gray texl as UILabel and put it on UISearchBar as subview.
Or you can write your own class, subclassing UISearchBar with this functional.